# Button que ejecute una accion mientras lo presione en un tiempo prolongado

Tags: android, android-studio

Estimados

Necesito que un button mientras este presionado se ejecute una accion X 
ejemplo

mientras presiono que vaya incrementando un contador y cuando deje de presionar se quede parado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con una Tarea Asyncrona 
así :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnContador;
    boolean estaPresionado = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnContador = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContador);

        btnContador.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        if (!estaPresionado) {
                            estaPresionado = true;
                            new EnviarContadorTarea().execute();
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        estaPresionado = false;

                }
                return true;
            }

        });
    }

    private class EnviarContadorTarea extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            while(estaPresionado) {
                AumentarContador();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        private void AumentarContador(){
            int contador = 0;
            contador = contador+1;
            Log.d("CONTADOR", "Valor: " + String.valueOf(contador));
        }

    }
}
```

En tu activity pones un inner class AsyncTask y alli pones la acción que quieres que suceda mientras cierto valor sea cierto, en nuestro caso, mientras el botón este presionado.

Poniendo una variable Boolean que diga si el botón esta presionado o no, si el botón se mantiene presionado, esta variable se mantendrá True y si esta variable se mantiene true , la acción del Thread se repetirá hasta que deje de ser true , agregando también un sleep, para que la acción tenga una pequeña pausa siempre antes de suceder.

Answer (score 1):

Por medio de un Asynctask se puede realizar la tarea que hace que un contador sea incrementado.

```
  //Define variable para validar estado.
  private boolean presionado = false;

    //Obtiene referencia de boton.
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClic);
    //Asigna OnTouchListener
    myButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (!presionado) {
                        presionado = true;
                        //AsyncTask que ejecuta Tarea.
                        new AsyncTaskCounter().execute();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    presionado = false;
                    Log.d("CONTADOR", "Detiene contador");
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Mediante este `Asynctask`, se ejecuta la tarea `taskIncrementaContador`:

```
private class AsyncTaskCounter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    int contador = 0;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        while(presionado) {
            taskIncrementaContador();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void taskIncrementaContador(){
        contador++;
        Log.d("CONTADOR", "Valor: " + String.valueOf(contador));
    }

}
```

Al presionar se imprime el valor del contador cada `n` milisegundos (en este caso 500) e imprime el valor del contador, al terminar escribe el mensaje que define el botón dejo de ser presionado.

Ejemplo:

```
Valor: 1
Valor: 2
Valor: 3
Valor: 4
Valor: 5
Detiene contador
Valor: 1
Valor: 2
Valor: 3
Detiene contador
```